# Hadoop Data Corrupted Following Power Failure

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop and learning to use it by working with a small cluster where each node is an Ubuntu Server VM. The cluster consists of 1 name node and 3 data nodes with a replication factor of 3. After a power loss on the machine hosting the VMs, all files stored in the cluster were corrupted and with the blocks storing those files missing. No queries were running at the time power was lost and no files were being written to or read from the cluster.

If I shut down the VMs correctly (even without first stopping the Hadoop cluster), then the data is preserved and I don't run into any issues with missing or corrupted blocks.

The only information I've been able to find suggested setting `dfs.datanode.sync.behind.writes` to `true`, but this did not resolve the issue (killing the VMs from the host causes the same issue as a power failure). The information I found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) seems to indicate this property will only have an effect when writing data to the disk.

I also tried running `hdfs namenode -recover`, but this did not resolve the issue. Ultimately I had to remove the data stored in the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` directory, rebooted each VM in the cluster to remove any Hadoop files in `/tmp` and reformatted the name node before copying the data back into the cluster from local file storage.

I understand that having all nodes in the cluster running on the same hardware and only 3 data nodes to go with a replication factor of 3 is not an ideal configuration, but I'd like a way to ensure that any data that is already written to disk is not corrupted by a power loss. Is there a property or other configuration I need to implement to avoid this in the future (besides separate hardware, more nodes, power backup, etc.)?

EDIT: To clarify further, the issue I'm trying to resolve is data corruption, not cluster availability. I understand I need to make changes to the overall cluster architecture to improve reliability, but I'd like a way to ensure data is not lost even in the event of a cluster-wide power failure.

Comment: And the data is fine if you properly shutdown your VMs?

Comment: Yes, if I shut down the VMs properly then I don't run into any issues (edited my question to include this).

Comment: What about setting up NameNode HA?

Comment: There is a whole page dedicated to preventing failures. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html

Comment: The issue I'm trying to resolve here isn't cluster down time, but rather data loss. I can try implementing an HA HDFS cluster, but this seems to be designed to prevent a cluster from being unavailable due to the name node being down. Would this also prevent data corruption even if all nodes (including name nodes) were lost due to a power failure?

Comment: @df7675 HDFS survives power failures. You are losing the blocks but not the namenode edits? Where is the data directory mounted?

Comment: @franklinsijo I'm not sure I understand your question, but when I run `hdfs namenode -recover` the command runs without any prompts that might indicate it found an error. The three data nodes each have their respective data directories set in `hdfs-site.xml`. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, I'm just new to using Hadoop.

Comment: Are the data directories empty in the event of VM crash? If yes, what about the directory set for `dfs.namenode.name.dir`?

Comment: I know the directory for `dfs.namenode.name.dir` is not empty in the event of a crash. I'm not sure about the data directories on the data nodes and unfortunately I'm not in a position to initiate a failure to test this at the moment, but my instinct is that they would not be empty. I can try tomorrow morning, I'm in eastern US so it's nearly 6PM here. What would this be an indication of?